# Adding a custom location to File | Open | File in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Does anyone know how to add a user-defined (custom) location/directory for opening a file in SQL Server 2008?  E.g. when I go to File menu, then Open, then choose File, it brings up a window with my last location.  On the left, I have 3 shortcuts: Desktop, My Projects, and My Computer.  In SQL Server 2005, you could (apparently) add your own location shortcuts in the registry (according to this thread: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic907188-391-1.aspx).  This method does not appear to work for 2008.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using SQL Server 2008 you need to use 100 instead of 90 in the path.

```
\HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\Open Find\Places\UserDefinedPlaces
```

Add one key Place0.
Add two string values in Place0, Name and Path.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I figured that part out but it still doesn't seem to work. Does it require one or two keys?

Comment: @tuseau Updated answer with some pretty pictures :)